# Catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in backward?

Tags: java

I creating pacman game. I have array of size 15x15, total 225fields. When I move from 255 to i.e.256, I got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, this makes sense. So I can catch it and do some operation, lets say I set new starting point of pacman. But if I go **from field 75 to 74** nothing happened.
So I asking, can I somehow catch this and do some operation, like I mention above.

Comment: I am afraid if you don't add some code examples, stack trace, logs, etc, your chances to get helped are very low.

Comment: Your question is not clear, also did you mean when I move from 225 to 226? What do you want when you move from 75 to 74?

Comment: You shouldn't catch it, you should avoid it from occurring by doing proper bounds checking (or even wrapping around if that makes sense).

Comment: thank you for your effort guys, @Alex Shesterov fix my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not rely on `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for normal logic. This exception is an indication of a programming error.

Instead, you should check the index before incrementing it:

```
if (currentIndex == 255) {
  // "special logic"
} else {
  // "usual logic"
}
```

This way you can also handle any "special" indexes, e.g.

```
if ((currentIndex + 1) % 15 == 0) {
  // "special logic"
} else {
  // "usual logic"
}
```

---

Another point: consider using two indexes - x and y - if you are programming a 2-D game.
Every move modifies x and/or y, which can easily "wrap around" like in pacman (e.g. 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 1 -> 2 -> ...).
And convert the (x,y)-Pair to an index only when you need to access the field element:

```
// Assuming that x and y are 1-based, not 0-based:
public FieldElement getFieldElementAtPosition(final int x, final int y) {
    final int index = (y - 1) * FIELD_WIDTH + x - 1;
    return fieldArray[index];
}
```

Comment: this makes, sense, thank you..with this should I fix my problem, have a nice day :)